# Where can I download old Wii demos?

Tags: nintendo-wii

Based on [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/15616/why-are-there-only-12-wii-demos/15653#answer-15653).

I do know that old Wii demos are removed from Wii shop, is there any place I can download them?

P.S. I have "original" Wii, so pirated versions won't work here and I'm not interested in pirated versions of the demos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wii demos can only be downloaded from the Wii Shop channel. If a demo is no longer in the Wii shop, there's no way you can download it.